# Magento 2 - Stock inventory qty problem

Tags: magento-2.1, stock, bug

I have Magento 2.1 installed.

When I change a quantity of some products (not all) since the record of a product nothing changes. If I go through the mass change there it changes.

Do you have any idea what's going on?

Comment: Did you use any migration tool?

Comment: is your cache disabled? if not please clean and re-index the products catalog data

Comment: i didn't use any migration tool.

Comment: i had try to clean cache and reindex. not working...

Answer (score 0):

did you try clearing cache and re-indexing? In developer mode a lot needs to be done from command prompt for this .